# Addind ISODate wrapper in Clojure

Tags: mongodb, clojure, monger

When I do a new Date() in an insert in  Mongodb shell it gets added as shown below with an ISODate wrapper.

```
ISODate("2017-12-06T12:56:01.908Z")
```

But when I format a date as an ISO using joda-time and add it via monger(Clojure Mongo Driver) it gets added as

```
2017-12-06T12:32:00.852Z
```

The ISO format is correct , but there is no ISODate wrapper around it and mongo for some reason do not respect it. Mongo TTLs do not work in the second case.

How do I add an ISODate wrapper to date in clojure or using monger?

Thank you

Comment: Because you are inserting string,  not ISODate Object (-;

Comment: yes. $date did it. Thanks.